# Issues with Laravel hasManyThrough relationship

Tags: laravel, relationships

I'm having issues using the hasManythrough relationship in larval.  Just following the documentation using the example there, which are:

```
countries
id - integer
name - string

users
id - integer
country_id - integer
name - string

posts
id - integer
user_id - integer
title - string
```

Here is how I set up the relationship in the models

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
public function posts() {

    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Post', 'App\User', 'user_id', 'country_id', 'id');
}
}
```

Here is the User model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function country() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\User');
}
}
```

Here is the Posts model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
     public function user() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
}
```

So, the website doesn't go through enough detail on how to extract the posts through the country model.  Using the routes file, this is the query I used

```
Route::get('posts/countries/{id}', function($id) {

$countries = App\Country::where('id', $id)->get();

return $countries->posts;

});
```

It looks to me like I set up the relationship up correctly the way the docs say to.  There is a country_id on the users table, so I'm not sure if the query is wrong or maybe I did set up the relationship incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually requesting the relationship, you are simply looking at the attribute on countries.

If you want to eagerload the posts in the query builder you will need to add `with('posts')` when you build the query. (Before you call `->get()` which executes the query and turns it into a collection.)

```
Route::get('posts/countries/{id}', function($id) {

$country = App\Country::with('posts')->where('id', $id)->first();

return $country->posts;

});
```

Or if you want to lazyload you can ask for the relationship on the country model by doing `->posts()` like this:

```
Route::get('posts/countries/{id}', function($id) {

$country = App\Country::with('posts')->where('id', $id)->first();

return $country->posts();

});
```

**Notice:** in both cases I changed the `->get()` to `->first()`. I assume you only want one country's posts returned.

`->get()` executes the query and returns the related models as a collection and `->first()` takes the first model from the query.

Answer (score 0):

@Nicklas Kevin Frank

Your solution didn't work for me.  at least not completely, but you were right in some respects.  I tinkered around, and discovered that the query worked like this better:

```
Route::get('posts/countries/{id}', function($id) {

$country = App\Country::where('id', $id)->first();

return view('country')->with('country', $country);
});
```

So, like you said, it diffidently needed the ->first() option, but it didn't need the with('posts') portion.  But much thanks my friend.  I couldn't have solved this without you.